# Can you give me a short step by step numerical example of radial basis function kernel trick? I would like to understand how to apply on perceptron

Tags: machine-learning, kernel-trick, libsvm

I understand well perceptron so put accent only on kernel but I am not familiar with matemathic expressions so please give me an numerical example and a guide on kernel.

**For example:**

My hyperplane of perceptron is x1*w1+x2*w2+x3*w3+b=0; The RBF kernel formula: k(x,z) = exp((-|x-z|^2)/2*variance^2) where takes action the radial basis function kernel here? Is x an input and what is z variable here? Or of what I have to calculate variance if it is variance in the formula? 
Somewhere I have understood so that I have to plug this formula in perceptron  decision function x1*w1+x2*w2+x3*w3+b=0; but how does it look look like If I plug in?

I would like to ask a numerical example to avoid confusion.

Comment: The feature space corresponding to the RBF kernel is of infinite dimension, so we can't provide a *numerical* example of the values of the weights in primal form (i.e. w1, w2, ... wn).  You would be better off understanding the polynomial kernel first, as that has a finite dimensional feature space.